# Querying and comparing Firestore serverTimestamp

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm fairly new to Firebase/Firestore and I'm querying some stored data for analysis via Cloud Function.

I can't figure out how to compare timestamp within a query.

Each document has a field set using `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`.

My initial query against the collection works, using `ref.where("timestamp", ">=", startTime)` where startTime is a Date object.

However, when I iterate through a snapshot - using doc.data().timestamp. Logging this value I get something like 2018-05-10T22:51:37.236Z which is not comparable.

Can I transform the doc.data().timestamp in a way that I can compare against a unix timestamp or Date object?

Comment: `Date.parse('2018-05-10T22:51:37.236Z');`  Should be able to use `.getTime()` on that object to get milliseconds.